# Laravel Image source not readable error

Tags: laravel, intervention

I am working on uploading a video locally and then use it locally to upload to s3. It successfully uploads to s3 but I get this error:

> **Image source not readable**
>   `/var/www/yt/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDecoder`

I found this error when I was trying to delete the image after I uploaded it to s3. I think it is the reason the delete does not work. How do I fix the error?

```
public function avatar(Request $request)
{

    $imageData = $request->get('image');
    $img = Image::make($request->get('image'))->fit(300)->encode('jpg');

    // calculate md5 hash of encoded image
    $hash = md5($img->__toString());

    // use hash as a name
    $path = "avatars/{$hash}.jpg";

    // save it locally 
    $test = $img->save(storage_path($path));

    // $url = "/images/{$hash}.jpg"
    $url_local =  $path;

    $path = Storage::putFile('avatars', new File(storage_path($url_local)));
    if($path){
        //TODO make into event
        Storage::disk('local')->delete(storage_path($url_local));
       // \Debugbar::error($test);
    }
    $user = User::find(Auth::id());
    $user->avatar_url = $path;
    if ($user->save()) {
        return response()->json(['avatar' => $user->gen_avatar()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Storage::disk('local')->delete($local_url);` instead?

Comment: Behind the scenes, laravel should already know where to look for the file, you just need to pass in the location relative to the storage location

Comment: this is what should be going in as the deleted argument: `avatars/{$hash}.jpg`

Comment: @Derek I still get the Image source not readable error

Comment: @Derek I use a variable with avatars/{$hash}.jpg to delete the file

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if the path its being saved to is the proper path. Do you have access to the server to look at the contents of the storage folder?

Comment: @Derek yes I am developing local. All the files are uploaded correctly to my knowledge

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173494/discussion-between-derek-and-john-freedom).